# replace all occurences of a specific character in string

Tags: php, replace

Im trying to replace a certain character in a string, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have the following code so far:

```
$sname   = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $_POST['name']);
$semail  = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $_POST['email']);
$smessage    = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $_POST['message']);

$name    = str_replace('¤', '', $sname);
$email   = str_replace('¤', '.', $semail);
$message     = str_replace('¤', '.', $smessage);
```

I am not sure what's wrong. The goal is to replace all the "¤" signs of the string. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out here :)

Comment: If it doesn't work, there's an encoding mismatch between the `'¤'` literal in your source code (i.e. the encoding of the source file) and the posted data. Also, why specifically '¤'?

Comment: im using the '¤' as a seperator in my storage file, thats why :) so I should just try using another symbol for this?

Comment: maybe try with the utf8 encoding : '\xa4' and use utf8 php functions ?

Comment: `$sname = 'sjh¤k¤kj¤j';
echo str_replace('¤', '', $sname);`.
This peice of code works fine for me and its giving the output as 'sjhkkjj'.

Comment: I change the "seperator symbol" (¤) to ";" and it works fine now. Thanks for your quick feed back :) should I close question somehow or?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `escape character \` in your string pattern `('\\*')`

```
$name = str_replace('\\¤', '', $sname);
```